# Read file as hex in C

Tags: c, file

This is my current code:

```
#include "fileread.h"

typedef struct
{
    char Key[50];
    int KeyLen;
}   KeyStorage;

eKeyFileRes GetNewKeyFile(  char *path, UINT64 fileName, KeyStorage *keyStorage)
{
    char sbuf[1024];
    FILE* file;
    sprintf (sbuf, "%s\\%llu.dat", path, fileName);  
    file=fopen(sbuf, "r");

    if(file == NULL)
    {
        return KeyFileRes_NoKeyFound;
    }
    else 
    { 
        fread(keyStorage->Key,1,50, file);
        fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
        keyStorage->KeyLen = ftell(file);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return  KeyFileRes_NewKeyFound;
}
```

It works fine, however The problem is that I need to read that file and then save in `buffer(keyStorage->key)` but in hex.

Here is a file example:

```
6B53E460E5D944A1200BE51A91588B50D3E887081E5DA5F90ADD71CF88D83A3C469EDB56E6FD526A4946B781257FFC950367
```

Comment: So if I understood the first 4 bytes you want to be stored in `key` are 0x6b, 0x53, 0xe4, 0x60, given the file example in your question. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Or do you want a string of 100 characters + null terminator?

Comment: @MichaelWalz yes, you´re right

Comment: Hint: read the file 2 chars, by 2 chars, and for each couple of chars (that will be "6B", "53", etc.) use [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) to convert the string to an int and then write that int to the `key` array.

Comment: In that case you are reading the file incorrect, you need to read 100 characters to get the 50 hex bytes.

Comment: @MichaelWalz thank you! Could you tell me how to read the file by 2 chars?

Comment: @stark thank you! Could you give me an example of how to read the file correctly?

Comment: @JuanManuelBoschetti `fread(tempbuffer,1,2, file); tempbuffer[2] = 0; int value = strtol(tempbuffer, NULL, 16);`

Comment: @MichaelWalz I tried this code, but in value I get a "107" with the first 2 chars "6B"

Comment: @JuanManuelBoschetti then you should ask about that code, maybe in another question.

Comment: @JuanManuelBoschetti actually `107` is the correct decimal value for `0x6b`. What did _you_ expect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you an idea:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {    
  char string[] = "6B53E460E5D9";   // NUL terminated sample string
  int length = strlen(string);      // get length of sample string

  for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 2)
  {
    char tmp[3];    
    tmp[0] = string[i];                             // copy 2 chars
    tmp[1] = string[i+1];                           //   "
    tmp[2] = 0;                                     // put the NUL terminator
    int value = strtol(tmp, NULL, 16);              // transform hex string to value
    printf("%d  %02x  %d\n", i / 2, value, value);  // show results
  }
}
```